# Load data in HBase from HDFS without using Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs, apache-pig

I have `.csv` files in `HDFS`. I want to load these in `HBASE` tables without using `Pig` script.

Is there any other way available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be several ways. But some of the options are like below.

#### Option 1: Simple way is [`ImportTsv`](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv)

`ImportTsv` is a utility that will load data in TSV format into HBase. It has two distinct usages: loading data from TSV format in HDFS into HBase via Puts, and preparing StoreFiles to be loaded via the completebulkload.

To load data via `Put`s (i.e., non-bulk loading):

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c <tablename> <hdfs-inputdir>
```

To generate StoreFiles for bulk-loading:

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=hdfs://storefile-outputdir <tablename> <hdfs-data-inputdir>
```

These generated StoreFiles can be loaded into HBase via Section 14.1.10, “CompleteBulkLoad”.

Example `hbase> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=,  -Dimporttsv.columns="c1,c2,c3...." hdfs://servername:/tmp/yourcsv.csv`

#### Option 2 : Custom map-reduce way

Write a mapreduce program and csv parser in case you need to parse the csv which is complex

[see example here](https://github.com/Paschalis/HBase-Bulk-Load-Example)